# When creating Purchase order i am getting error like Number sequence does not exist

Tags: axapta

when creating the purchase order i am getting error like number sequence does not exist . number sequence are filled in following link (Accounts Payable->Setup-> Accounts payable Parameter) please help me out.and how to set number sequence for Accounts payable module.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fszbv.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at the [help/on-Topic] page on what is considered on topic for Stack Overflow. Your question is not a good fit and you may have better luck getting an answer in another community like e.g. the [Dynamics Community](https://community.dynamics.com/).

Answer (score 0):

try to find on web more informatin, but more less you have to set the value (functional work).

Try to read thesepost above:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242127.aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh802995.aspx

https://daxing2012.wordpress.com/2013/07/03/ax2012-number-sequences-scope-parameters/

Good Work!

Comment: Yes I set number sequence in Procurement and sourcing then only its throwing error at the time of filling values for created purchase id.

Comment: It will throw error at the time of filling Purchase Order Lines details.

Comment: It will throw error at the time of filling Purchase Order Lines details.PO is creating.

Comment: Hi @**user3571565** can you sho the erro log ? Please.

Comment: Hi @Ulisses please click the link for error log          http://imgur.com/a/BJirw

Comment: Hi @ Ulisses Please reply to this

Comment: Hi @Beta, I'm apologize I not see all time the post.
Because this I think is an parametrization error, Is's difficulty to find the cause.
So, in any case: the number sequence is setted in USE ? loo like this : https://community.dynamics.com/cfs-file/__key/communityserver-discussions-components-files/33/Sequence-number.png ?
And the scope is right like : https://axtechhouse.wordpress.com/2011/07/26/number-sequence-scope-segments-in-ax-2012/ ?
The problem is the system not see the Sequence, in all Setup AccontPayable and Procurement And Sourcing  module you have all sequence set ?

Comment: Hi @Ulisses I did same what you mentioned above , then only its throwing error.and one more thing if i put debugger compiler will go fine at the end it is not going into NumberSeq Class where error is throwing.